# HttpCaching - ETag generated per client or per token?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, http-caching, cachecow

I am working in ASP.NET WEB API with oAuth2 bearer token authentication and HttpCaching with CacheCow.

The implementation already done and i am verifying the code and got confused with caching.

**Cache Handler Configuration:**

The cache configuration code is below;

```
        var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myContext"].ConnectionString;
        var sqlServerEtagStore = new InMemoryEntityTagStore();
        var cacheHandler = new CachingHandler(config, sqlServerEtagStore);
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(cacheHandler);
```

**Scenarios and working steps :**

1. There is one table named 'dataTable' which includes field named
   'email'.
2. I have identity tables so users are in aspnetUser table.
3. Data retrieved based on logged user email address (where
       dataTable.email = current principle.Identity.Name).
4. dataTable  includes 10 records. 9 records for user1 and only 1
   record for user2.
5. I used 'Postman Rest Client' to test and logged 2 users. So i have 2
       tokens for logged users.

**Clarifications:**

1. From configuration, i think sqlserver is configured for persistent
   storage. But after used InMemoryEntityTagStore. Why this.? so
   configuration is wrong? What in 'InMemoryEntityTagStore' class?

> ```
> var sqlServerEtagStore = new InMemoryEntityTagStore();
> var cacheHandler = new CachingHandler(config, sqlServerEtagStore);
> ```

2. From scenario, I used get request to get data with user1 token. Here
   i got 9 records with etag generated. Then i request to get data with
   user2 token. Here also i got the same etag. is this correct? so eTag
   is generated per client? is my testing scenario is worng? i thought like for each resource separate tag is generated so data based on user is cached

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: no. i think etag generated per client, not based on user. But still didn't confirm it